# Передача переменной в success функцию Ajax-запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Не могу понять почему не передается переменная в `success`. Пробую передавать так:

```
function start_chat()
{
    var form = $('#form')[0];
    $('body').on('submit', '#form', function()
    {
        var textarea = $(form).find('input');
        start_func(textarea);
        return false;
    });
    function start_func(textarea)
    {
        var send_ajax_data =
        {
            //query
        }
        $.post
        (
            'link',
            send_ajax_data,
            function(data)
            {
                console.log(textarea);
                update_timer(); //обновим таймер 
            },
            'JSON'
        );
    }
}
start_func();

var timer;
function update_timer()
{
    if (timer)
    {
        clearTimeout(timer); //если таймер уже был, сбрасываем
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        start_func();
    }, 5000);
}
update_timer();
```

Сам запрос работает отлично. Результат возвращается без ошибок. А вот переменную не передает. Из-за чего это происходит?

Comment: @Regent `console.log(textarea);` возвращает `undefined`. Ваш вариант не получается применить.

Comment: @Regent Если выводить переменную внутри функции `function start_func(textarea) { console.log(textarea);  }` то выводиться без проблем. А если же в самом `$.post();` выводить через консоль эту переменную, то выводиться `undefined`.

Comment: @Regent, код действительно не весь, т.к. он огромен. `var start_func(textarea);` не правильно я вставил, там в реальном коде `var` нету

Comment: @Regent, сейчас весь основной код предоставлен.

Comment: Вас не беспокоит, что у вас в 2 из 3 вызовов функции `start_func` в качестве аргумента ничего не передаётся? При этих вызовах переменная `textarea` действительно равна `undefined`.

Comment: @Regent, 2-я служит первоначальному вызову функции, а с 3-ей функции я знаю как быть

Comment: А вопрос ещё актуален? Или проблема всё же была в тех двух вызовах?

Comment: @Regent, вы что-то изменили, а вот понять что именно, не могу (я про код)

Comment: Это потому что я ничего не менял, кроме оформления. Весь ваш код и его логика на месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вдаваясь в подробности работы скрипта, поправил только работу с функцией `start_func()`

```
var formSelector = '#form';
function start_chat()
{
    $(document).on('submit', formSelector, function()
    {
        start_func($(this).find('input')); // вам случаем не значение это поля нужно? Может val() ?
        return false;
    });
    function start_func(textarea)
    {
        var send_ajax_data =
        {
            //query
        }
        $.post
        (
            'link',
            send_ajax_data,
            function(data)
            {
                console.log(textarea);
                update_timer(); //обновим таймер 
            },
            'JSON'
        );
    }
}
start_func($(formSelector).find('input')); // параметры то забыли передать

var timer;
function update_timer()
{
    if (timer)
    {
        clearTimeout(timer); //если таймер уже был, сбрасываем
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        start_func($(formSelector).find('input')); // параметры то забыли передать
    }, 5000);
}
update_timer();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает!

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
function start_func(textarea) {
    var textarea = textarea|| {}; // так создадим локальную переменную
    var success = function(data){
        console.log(textarea);
        update_timer(); //обновим таймер 
    };
    var send_ajax_data = {};
    $.post(
        'link',
        send_ajax_data,
        success,
        'JSON'
    );
}
```

*P.S. не самое лучшее оформление кода у вас*